# More efficient jQuery Hover to fadeIn/fadeOut for multiple divs?

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I've got the basics of hovering over an image and showing div of text below the image. But how can this be made more efficient?

As it stands, I'd have to have four different functions to fadein/out the corresponding text for each image.

I need to keep the dl and dt markup of the images, but the markup of the divs holding the text can be changed.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{    
    $("dt.imgone").hover(
      function () {
        $("div.textone").fadeIn('fast');
      }, 
      function () {
        $("div.textone").fadeOut('fast');
      }
    );
});
```

**html**

```
<div id="imagegallerydiv">

   <dl class="gallery"><dt class="imgone"><img alt="img" src="one.jpg"></dt>
   <dt>Image Title One</dt></dl>

   <dl class="gallery"><dt class="imgtwo"><img alt="img" src="two.jpg"></dt>
   <dt>Image Title Two</dt></dl>

   <dl class="gallery"><dt class="imgthree"><img alt="img" src="three.jpg"></dt>
   <dt>Image Title Three</dt></dl>

   <dl class="gallery"><dt class="imgfour"><img alt="img" src="four.jpg"></dt>
   <dt>Image Title Four</dt></dl>

</div>

<div id="wide-text-div-under-all-images">

     <div class="textone">Lorem Ipsum One</div>

     <div class="texttwo">Lorem Ipsum Two</div>

     <div class="textthree">Lorem Ipsum Three</div>

     <div class="textfour">Lorem Ipsum Four</div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#imagegallerydiv {width: 700px; height:200px; margin:5px; text-align: center;}

dl.gallery {width: 97px; text-align: center; float: left;}

.gallery dt {width: 80px; margin-top:2px; font-size: .7em; text-align:center;}

#wide-text-div-under-all-images div {display: none;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#imagegallerydiv dt[class]").hover(
      function () {
        var index = $(this).parent().index();
        $("#wide-text-div-under-all-images div").eq(index).fadeIn('fast');
      }, 
      function () {
        var index = $(this).parent().index();
        $("#wide-text-div-under-all-images div").eq(index).fadeOut('fast');
      }
    );
});
```

[**Code example on jsfiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/jxX5v/)

Another option would be to use `delegate()` so you are not binding a bunch of event handlers to the `dt`directly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#imagegallerydiv").delegate("dt[class]", "hover", function(e) {
        if (e.type === "mouseenter") {
            var index = $(this).parent().index();
            $("#wide-text-div-under-all-images div").eq(index).fadeIn('fast');
        }
        if (e.type === "mouseleave") {
            var index = $(this).parent().index();
            $("#wide-text-div-under-all-images div").eq(index).fadeOut('fast');
        }
    });
});
```

**[Example of `delegate()`](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/jxX5v/3/)**

Comment: Thanks, but under 1.4.4 and Safari, the first example doesn't hide the previous text div, so they accumulate; and then the second example flickers the text div and sometimes hides the text on cursor pause over the image.

Comment: I had a small typo in the first example. Never was calling fadeOut.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the issue of the text disappearing when pausing over the image in safari or chrome.  Does it happen to you in the fiddle as well?

Comment: Thanks, my mistake, the text is fine. Thanks for the help. I'm thinking now I want to try and use a click with slidetoggle instead of hover so the text div doesn't jump. If you're up for it, I opened a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813066/change-jquery-function-from-hover-to-slidetoggle

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way (haven't tested it but it should work)

```
$("#imagegallerydiv dt").hover(
      function () {
          var idx = $(this).parent().index();
          $("#wide-text-div-under-all-images div").eq(idx).fadeIn('fast');
      }, 
      function () {
          var idx = $(this).parent().index();
          $("#wide-text-div-under-all-images div").eq(idx).fadeOut('fast');
      }
    );
```

EDITED the `idx =` part

Comment: Thanks. This works fine, but when I pause the mouse over an image, the text disappears.

Comment: @songdogtech when you mouse over an image which text dissapears? Also, it would help to post the relevant css

Comment: Thanks, my mistake. Don't know what I was doing. Added CSS above. I'm going to try and use slidetoggle and a click function to hopefully get the text div to not flicker. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813066/change-jquery-function-from-hover-to-slidetoggle

Answer (score 0):

```
var $divs = $("#wide-text-div-under-all-images div");
$("#imagegallerydiv dl").each(function(index) {
    $("img", this).hover(function() {
        $divs.eq(index).fadeIn("fast");
    },
    function() {
        $divs.eq(index).fadeOut("fast");
    });
});
```