# Change jQuery function from hover to slideToggle

Tags: jquery, hover, slidetoggle

With help from SOers, I was able to make more efficient a hover and fadein/fadeout function to show text divs under this image layout. But I'd like to work with slideToggle because with hover, the text flickers and the divs bounce. How would I adapt this function to use slideToggle where the toggle requires a click on each image?

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Ckrtu/11/

This is an image of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

**This is the old hover function**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#imagegallerydiv").delegate("dt[class]", "hover", function(e) {
        if (e.type === "mouseenter") {
            var index = $(this).parent().index();
            $("#wide-text-div-under-all-images div").eq(index).fadeIn('fast');
        }
        if (e.type === "mouseleave") {
            var index = $(this).parent().index();
            $("#wide-text-div-under-all-images div").eq(index).fadeOut('fast');
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#imagegallerydiv {width: 700px; height:200px; margin:5px; text-align: center;}

dl.gallery {width: 97px; text-align: center; float: left;}

.gallery dt {width: 80px; margin-top:2px; font-size: .7em; text-align:center;}

#wide-text-div-under-all-images div {display: none;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="imagegallerydiv">

   <dl class="gallery"><dt class="imgone"><img alt="img" src="one.jpg"></dt>
   <dt>Image Title One</dt></dl>

   <dl class="gallery"><dt class="imgtwo"><img alt="img" src="two.jpg"></dt>
   <dt>Image Title Two</dt></dl>

   <dl class="gallery"><dt class="imgthree"><img alt="img" src="three.jpg"></dt>
   <dt>Image Title Three</dt></dl>

   <dl class="gallery"><dt class="imgfour"><img alt="img" src="four.jpg"></dt>
   <dt>Image Title Four</dt></dl>

 <dl class="gallery"><dt class="imgfive"><img alt="img" src="four.jpg"></dt>
   <dt>Image Title Five</dt></dl>

</div>

<div id="wide-text-div-under-all-images">

     <div class="textone">Lorem Ipsum One</div>

     <div class="texttwo">Lorem Ipsum Two</div>

     <div class="textthree">Lorem Ipsum Three</div>

     <div class="textfour">Lorem Ipsum Four</div>

     <div class="textfive">Lorem Ipsum Five</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/samccone/z83Kx/

I think this example is much simpler to understand and fits the desired outcome better then what you were using before.

Just set the text that you want to show as an attr within the div that is to be clicked

`<dl class="gallery"><dt class="imgthree" to_show='this is text3'><img alt="img" src="http://www.placehold.it/75x100"></dt>`

hope that this helps

Comment: Thanks, that works pretty well. I'm wondering if there's a way to get the text into the text divs below the images? There is quite a bit of text and links for each, and I don't want to stuff it into the markup for the gallery.

Comment: Yes there is I will post a revision in a moment

Comment: @samccone - Thanks! That works great. But: (like always, it seems) there's one issue I don't know how to fix: any kind of html markup within the text span breaks something, and the spans don't swap and stack up. So is it possible to have the function ignore any markup, i.e. `<p>, <p class="text">, <i>, etc` within the span?

Comment: hmm, i added markup in the the spans and everything seems to be working fine... can you post an example of the issue you are seeing

Comment: @samccone: Ah, you're right, jsfiddle works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/z83Kx/13/  What is broken is on my site (not yet public) where I'm using this inside of a tab from jQuery Tabs UI. No errors shown in Firebug. What happens is all the spans of text stack up down the page, and only when they have all loaded do they rotate somewhat. Mystery. I removed all other jQuery except the tabs init and no luck.

Comment: Ya put in a fiddle and I will see what I can do tomorrow

Comment: Really appreciate the help. Here's a new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yfs2V/3/ It's a strange bug: on my localhost the text stacks up after a full page reload; in jsfiddle, after an Update. Switching to another tab and then back will sometimes clear the issue.

Comment: this is really odd, I played with in firefox then chrome, it works fine in firefox but not in chrome... which makes me think that it an issue with the js tabs or maybe a issue with jquery ick....

Comment: Thanks, but I something is broken as well. I'm trying slidetoggle now; I have slidetoggle working in a different way on the same site. If you're interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837563/how-to-fix-this-jquery-slidetoggle

Answer (score 1):

you may want to use this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $textUnderImage = $("#wide-text-div-under-all-images div");
    $('dt[class]').toggle(
        // first function fired on first click
        function() {
            var index = $(this).parent().index();
            if($textUnderImage.is(":visible")) {
                $textUnderImage.fadeOut('fast');
            }
            $("#wide-text-div-under-all-images div").eq(index).fadeIn('fast');
        },
        // second function fired on second click
        function() { 
            var index = $(this).parent().index();
            $("#wide-text-div-under-all-images div").eq(index).fadeOut('fast');
        }
    );
```

The first function will show the text on first click, and the second function will hide the text on second click and so on...

`toggle` method will fire the functions inside it sequentially.  So each time you click the handler, one method after the other is processed once. You can add as much as many function inside a toggle method and each function will be executed on each click sequentially.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but the text divs stack up on tp of each other. Is there a way to have only one text div show at a time? Your code: http://jsfiddle.net/56aUw/1/

Comment: Thanks, but after one trip through the links, it stops working. Something isn't getting cleared.