# How to fix this jQuery SlideToggle?

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

What I'm trying to do is independently slidetoggle text divs under a row of images when those images - in a dl/dt gallery - are clicked, like so:

[image: dl and dt gallery]

But of course I'm doing at least a few things wrong. Could be complicated that the markup is in a jQuery Tab, but that may not be the case. **jsfiddle here:** http://jsfiddle.net/Yfs2V/8/

I think the function is problematic:

**jQuery function:**

```
$(".bkcontent").hide();
$("#bookimggallery dt").click(function() {
    $(".bkcontent").hide();
$(this).parent().children(".bkcontent").slideToggle(500); });
```

**the HTML:**

```
<div id="bookimggallery">

    <dl class="gallery"><dt><img alt="img" src=""></dt>
        <dt>Image Title One</dt></dl>

    <dl class="gallery"><dt><img alt="img" src=""></dt>
        <dt>Image Title Two</dt></dl>

    <dl class="gallery"><dt><img alt="img" src=""></dt>
        <dt>Image Title Three</dt></dl>

    <dl class="gallery"><dt><img alt="img" src=""></dt>
        <dt>Image Title Four</dt></dl>

    <dl class="gallery"><dt><img alt="img" src=""></dt>
        <dt>Image Title Five</dt></dl>

</div>

<div id="booktextdiv">

<div class="bkcontent">Lorum Ipsum....</div>

<div class="bkcontent">Lorum Ipsum....</div>

<div class="bkcontent">Lorum Ipsum....</div>

<div class="bkcontent">Lorum Ipsum....</div>

<div class="bkcontent">Lorum Ipsum....</div>

</div>
```

**the CSS:**

```
#bookimggallery { width: 600px; height:200px; margin:2px; text-align: center;}

dl.gallery {width: 93px; text-align: center; float: left;}

.gallery dt { width: 80px; margin-top:2px; font-size: .7em; text-align:center;}

#booktextdiv span {display:none}

*(omitted tabs CSS for clairity)*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems going on here. I think the main being the selectors you are using to access the click on the book and also its text doesn't appear to be linked to the book gallery item in any way.

I have modified your [code slightly **here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yfs2V/10/)

The basic changes are **HTML**:

```
<dl class="gallery" rel="one">
```

*Add a `rel="blahh"` to the `dl` of each book, this will correspond to the text div*

```
<div class="bkcontent" id="one">
```

*Add an `id="blah"` to the `div` that contains the text for the book*

The **jQuery** changes:

```
$("#bookimggallery  dt").click(function() {
    $(".bkcontent").hide();
    var textid = $(this).parent('dl').attr('rel');
    $('#'+textid).slideToggle(500); 
});
```

*The selector now selects all `dt`'s within the `div` with the `id="bookimggallery"`*

*It then gets the **id** from the `rel="blah"`, then slideToggles it.*

Without completely rearranging your code layout this is how I would do this.

Comment: Thanks, great fix. Still learning jQuery. One issue that I found is that on a full page load, all the .bkcontent divs woudl show as expanded, so I added a `$(".bkcontent").hide();` to a doc ready function that hides the Tabs CSS untill fully loaded, and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Well for one your class is `bookimggallery` and not `imagegallerydiv`, for another, the text is not a child of your `<dl>` elements so `$(this).parent().children(".bkcontent")` doesn't contain any elements.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the #bookimggallery. How do I select elements in the booktextdiv?

Answer (score 1):

Checking [this reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dl.asp) it looks like your use of DL/DT/DD is slightly off.

Consider reorganizing your html to

```
<dl>
  <dt class="gallery"><img alt="img" src="">Image Title One</dt>
  <dd> description text one</dd>

  <dt class="gallery"><dt><img alt="img" src="">Image Title Two</dt>
  <dd> description text two</dd>
</dl>
```

Your jquery would then look like

```
$("dd").hide();
$("dt.gallery").click(function() {
  $("dd").hide(); // or $("dd:visible").slideToggle(500);
  $(this).next("dd").slideToggle(500);
});
```